# Get duration of video file from command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, video, metadata

In Windows, is there a way to get the duration (e.g. in seconds) of an AVI file from the command line?

I'm fine with using 3<sup>rd</sup> party tools - the more common, the better.

Comment: It's not possible to retrieve the duration of a **transport stream** what you can do is *estimate the duration*. Such as — Duration of a `MPEG-TS` video file is not possible retrieve (even you can't estimate) if you don't iterate all the packets or estimate the bitrate of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/) is a great tool for extracting such information, there's both a GUI and CLI version. [Here](http://umibe.googlecode.com/svn/!svn/bc/8/trunk/umibe/resources/MediaInfo/Contrib/CLI_Help.doc) is a summary of its basic command line options, you'll probably want to pass it just the filename or include a `-f` switch for more details.

Comment: Just found out about this tool on my own :). For the reference, here's the command line that outputs duration in millisesconds: `MediaInfo.exe --Output=Video;%Duration% file.avi`  BTW Running `MediaInfo.exe --info-parameters` to see what it can output is a bit overwhelming :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following PowerShell script

```powershell
$path = $Args[0]
$shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
$folder = Split-Path $path
$file = Split-Path $path -Leaf
$shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($folder)
$shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($file)

$shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27);
```

Save it as a *.ps1 file, e.g. `duration.ps1`. Call it like `duration.ps1 path\to\video\file`

It'll give time in `hh:mm:ss` form. If you want it as seconds then change the last line to `[timespan]::Parse($shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27)).TotalSeconds`

This works for any types that has duration that Windows can read. I made it from the below sources

- [Get MP3/MP4 File’s MetaData](https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2016/10/15/powershell-get-mp3mp4-files-metadata-and-how-to-use-it-to-make-you-life-easy/)
- [Use PowerShell to Find Metadata from Photograph Files](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-metadata-from-photograph-files/)

Of course because it uses Shell.Application, you can use any WScript languages to achieve the same purpose. For example here's a hybrid bat-jscript version, just save it as a normal *.bat file and pass the video file path to it:

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
cscript //e:jscript //nologo "%~f0" %1
exit /b

@end

// JScript Section

var filepath = WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
var slash = filepath.lastIndexOf('\\');
var folder = filepath.substring(0, slash);
var file = filepath.substring(slash + 1);

var shell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var shellFolder = shell.NameSpace(folder);
shellfile = shellFolder.ParseName(file);
var duration = shellFolder.GetDetailsOf(shellfile, 27);
WScript.Echo(duration);
```

You'll also need to split time and multiple the hours/minutes to get seconds, but that's trivial